# blackberry code signing for phonegap without using eclipse

Tags: blackberry, cordova

Working on a blackberry application. So far was working on eclipse. Now moved to webworks sdk 2.2 that does not support the eclipse plugin. Followed the instructions on the phonegap page to get the cod files. Now that I have the cod files how can I sign them? I use the ant command to generate the cod files.

```
 ant build Buildfile: C:\Dev\bbw\sample\build.xml
```

I have the code signing password in project.properties.

**EDIT**  Used the signaturetool Java -jar Signaturetool.jar. When I hand it the cod files it says no signing required. When I do a OTA install on my device it errors out saying - module attempts to access a secure api.

Answer (score 1):

This works. Go to your blackberry install folder and type out the following command. Of course this assumes that your project is in the proper zip format - eclipse does it for you but if not you would just need to package your project into a zip file.

in command type:

```
bbwp yourproject.zip -g mypassword
```

It will generate and sign the cod files required

Comment: This worked for me as well. The Signature Tool was freezing during the signing process though and I found out I had to downgrade to Java 1.6 (from 1.7) due to a compatibility problem (see here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/SignatureTool-Stops-Responding-While-Signing/ta-p/1286833 )

Comment: @user529265 - Can you write more detailed instructions out? Right now I have an OTAInstaller Folder. Do I zip those up?

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using ant. Connect your device to PC using USB cable and run following command.

```
ant blackberry load-device
```

You need to run above command (in cmd prompt) where you have blackberry.xml file.

(You need to install blackberry desktop software for the above command to work.You can download the same from http://us.blackberry.com/apps-software/desktop/ )

Above command will do following things for you..
1.build your application.
2.Launch signature tool and ask for password.
3.Once you enter password it will sign all the .cod files and other required files.
4.Install application on your phone.